# How to rearrange index after groupby and value_counts

Tags: pandas, sorting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3L0v.png)

I have the following Series where I applied a groupBy and then .value_counts. I would like the order of the createGroup column to be True -> False.

Does anybody know how?  Thanks in advance

I have tried using sort_values but it does not work

```
df['createGroup'].sort_values(['createGroup']).groupby(df['verification']).value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible input example?

Comment: Try `sort=False` in your groupby statement.

Comment: Although `groupby.value_counts` is not really needed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value_counts` makes an index out of your selected columns.

You need to use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), as True is sorted after False, make the order descending for this level:

```
out = (df[['verification', 'createGroup']]
       .value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)
       .sort_index(by=['verification', 'createGroup'], ascending=[True, False])
      )
```